# Agendamento de Tarefas

Tags: javascript, json

Gostaria de saber se é possível agendar tarefas com javascript, ou seja tenho um script em javascript e se fosse possível "claro" as 01:00 hora fosse executado automaticamente.

Sei que isso nas outras linguagem de servidor é possível, já ouvi algumas pessoas dizendo que utiliza o javascript para servidor.

```
--request GET "{url}/1/RecurrentPayment/{RecurrentPaymentId}"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--header "MerchantId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
--header "MerchantKey: 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
--header "RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
--data-binary
--verbose
```

Caso não seja possível, pode me dar uma ideia de como realizar esse procedimento?

Comment: em javascript, você quer que por exemplo uma mensagem seja exibida caso a pessoa esteja com o navegador aberto?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves, a mensagem não é necessária, eu preciso que o javascript realize somente as consulta via Get e faça um procedimento no banco.

Comment: neste caso você sabe que o cliente vai precisar ter a aba do navegador aberta né? Porque você não faz server side com PHP?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves, na verdade faz sim server side, com NODE.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia usar um setTimeout, calculando o tempo em milisegundos do momento atual até o momento da tarefa.
ex:
São 12:00 e quero agendar uma tarefa para as 13hs:
1h = 60min = 3600seg = 3600.000 mili

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Tarefa executada!!!!');
}, 3600000);
```

Lembrando que o setTimeout é assíncrono!
Para tarefas repetitivas, você pode ainda rodar um setInterval, ele vai executar a tarefa após X milissegundos.

O grande problema nesses métodos é que eles ficam registrados em memória apenas, assim, se seu servidor cair, eles não serão executados. Minha sugestão é criar uma tabela de tarefas agendadas, e na inicialização do servidor, listar as tarefas a executar e agendar todas usando um script.

Espero ter ajudado.